# Configuring Local Nexus Server

Tags: maven, nexus

I configured a Nexus server locally on my computer. And I configured several proxy for the company repositories and for the maven-central. If I type the url for an artifact in the browser such as `http://localhost:2312/repository/my_repo/junit/junit/4.9/junit-4.9.jar` the artifact is downloaded without problems.

But when I try to run the build using the prompt, when I type `mvn clean install` I get the message:`Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.9: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.9 from/to Nexus (http://localhost:2312/repository/my_repo/): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:2312/repository/my_repo/junit/junit/4.9/junit-4.9.pom. Return code is: 504, ReasonPhrase: Gateway Timeout.`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or forgetting to do?

Comment: Is there an http proxy server configured in your settings.xml file? If so, add the nexus host name to the proxy bypass list.

Comment: Yeap, there is an http proxy... I already done it. and localhost is listed on <nonProxyHosts>